# PowerShell - Convert String in variable to Datetime format

Tags: .net, powershell, datetime, parsing

How do I convert a string date held in a variable to a datetime format.

The variable `$stringdate` contains the string `'2020-04-10 09:15:30'` when I run the commands (1) below I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value "2020-04-10 09:15:30" to type "System.DateTime"`. 
Error: "String '2020-04-10 09:15:30' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

If I run commands (2) with the string `"2020-04-10 09:15:30"` instead of the variable `$stringdate` it doesn't error and returns `10 April 2020 09:15:30`??

```bash
#(1)

$date = $stringdate
    
[datetime]$date
```

```bash
# (2)
    
$date ="2020-04-10 09:15:30"
    
[datetime]$date
```

Comment: How did you obtain/create `$stringdate` in the first place?

Comment: it is a string from a text file using get-content

Comment: Given that `$stringdate = '2020-04-10 09:15:30'; [datetime] $stringdate` works fine, the implication is that the `$stringdate` read from a file contains something else - perhaps invisible control characters.

Comment: To put it differently: with the information currently contained in your question, the problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

You already wrote the cause for your issue in your question: You have a string not a Datetime. That is why you got an erorr. You must parse your string to a datetime object.

You can use ParseExact. If you want the format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', try this:

```
$stringDate = "2020-04-10 09:15:30"
$dateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($stringDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', $null)
echo $dateTime
```

Output:

`Friday, 10. April 2020 09:15:30`

For further information:
[ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0)

Comment: thanks that works but I want to convert the string '2020-04-10 09:15:30 in the variable $stringdate to be a datetime.
is there a way to do something like

`$date = $stringDate

$dateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($date, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss', $null)

[datetime]$dateTime`

without getting the error _ Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String '2020-04-10 09:15:30' was not recognized as a valid DateTime." _

Comment: @Nivag what you are doing is correct. However, you are parsing minutes instead of Months. Use a capital "M". So instead of "mm" use "MM".

Comment: MM stands for month and mm for minutes.

Comment: While this works, there is no need for `.ParseEact()`: a simple `[datetime]` _cast_, as attempted in the question, is enough: `$stringdate = '2020-04-10 09:15:30'; [datetime] $stringdate`. Therefore, the problem must be that  the `$stringdate` value read from a file either contains a different format or extraneous characters.